# Excel: Averageifs from a table with columns

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, average

I have a tab with a table. The table has over 30 different item names that are taking the average of over 180 types of items as the columns and dates as the rows. The example is the column is Apples and the next columns are Red Apples, then yellow apples and the Apples column is taking an average of the other specific types of items.

I created a separate tab with a table that can tell me the average of the Apple columns between two selected dates. This table as the item names as rows. I want to make this more dynamic though. Instead of an averageifs that hard codes each column (ie a:a for apples T:T for grapes) can I get the averageifs based on the different item names in one formula?

I am hardcoding each column to each item type, but am looking for a more dynamic solution.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should provide sample data and the formulas you already have - otherwise it is pretty hard to help you. Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question. Maybe this link will help you too: [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).